# Monotouch - Enable password reset feature on iOS app with Azure Mobile Apps Backend

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin iOS app, with Azure Mobile Apps backend integration. There's a login page, where I perform the necessary authentication when the user clicks the **Sign In** button.

[image: Login Page]

I would now like to enable the forgot password button, and have them reset theirs passwords, but I'm not sure how that works.

I have looked at this tutorial by Microsoft : [Set up self-service password reset for your consumers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-sspr/), but even with that, I'm still not sure how to tie in the logic for the password reset in code.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for Azure AD with Xamarin here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/

Looks like they recently added the forgotten password feature to the sample, so this should help you out.

Comment: Thank you. Let me have a look.